# VSCode through Mobaxterm cannot be moved, resized or maximized

Tags: ssh, remote-access, visual-studio-code, x11-forwarding

I'd like to try out VSCode. I code usually on Qt Creator on a remote machine with Ubuntu/Debian, which I access through Mobaxterm (ssh) with X11 forwarding on Windows. I installed the latest VSCode (`code_1.30.1-1545156774_amd64.deb`), and I ran it with `code`, but I can't maximize the window or move it in anyway. The maximize button is completely unresponsive and doesn't do anything. Trying to drag the window or resize it by hand also doesn't do anything.

Is there some configuration to do to make it do these things?

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing a similar issue.  Things were golden and something changed recently that borked this up.  Still trying to find a solution as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the answer:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/65232#issuecomment-449010667

in `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json`

```
"window.titleBarStyle": "native"
```

if the file doesn't exist, create a new one with this line:

```
{ "window.titleBarStyle": "native" }
```